# How to find a specific link within a given div jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, find

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="ally_request_container" data-type="ally" field-id="<?=$random_id;?>">
    <span class="ally_request_label">Request</span>
    <a class="ally_request" data-type="accept" href="#">Accept</a>
</div>
```

I want to be able to change the links data-type="accept" to data-type="remove", and change the link text from Accept to Remove, depending on what link I click, there could be 100's, thats why I use the parent div's field id to target what i'm clicking.

How do I find and change the mentioned?

I've got the following that I use to get a JSON response for the field-id:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ally_request").click(function(){
        var type = $(this).parent().attr('data-type');
        var this_type = $(this).attr('data-type');
        var field_id = $(this).parent().attr('field-id');
        var find = $("div").find("[field-id='" + field_id + "']");
        var position = find.position();

        alert('Type '+type);
        alert('This Type '+this_type);
        alert('Field ID '+field_id);
        alert('Find '+find);
        alert('Position '+position);

        switch(type){
            case 'ally':
                switch(this_type){
                    case 'accept':
                    $.getJSON('json.php', {action:'ally.accept',ally_id:field_id}, function(response){
                        if(response.status == 200){
                            var result = response.message;

                            //To reset the title and link data type
                            //change link data-type and text here
                        }
                        else{
                            alert(response.message);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                    default:
                        alert('Unknown Accept Result.');
                    break;
                }
            break;
            default:
                alert('Unknown Search Result.');
            break;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `this` reference inside the success handler since the execution context of the success handler is different, use a closure variable instead.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ally_request").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent();

        var type = $parent.attr('data-type');
        var this_type = $this.attr('data-type');
        var field_id = $parent.attr('field-id');
        var find = $("div").find("[field-id='" + field_id + "']");
        var position = find.position();

        alert('Type ' + type);
        alert('This Type ' + this_type);
        alert('Field ID ' + field_id);
        alert('Find ' + find);
        alert('Position ' + position);

        switch (type) {
            case 'ally':
                switch (this_type) {
                    case 'accept':
                        $.getJSON('json.php', {
                            action: 'ally.accept',
                            ally_id: field_id
                        }, function (response) {
                            if (response.status == 200) {
                                var result = response.message;

                                $this.attr('data-type', 'remove').text('Remove')
                                //To reset the title and link data type
                                //change link data-type and text here
                            } else {
                                alert(response.message);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('Unknown Accept Result.');
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                alert('Unknown Search Result.');
                break;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: great answer cheers, "You cannot use this reference" I thought something was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

add this in your click handler code:

```
$(this).attr('data-type', 'remove');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add selector to element then access

```
<a id="test" class="ally_request" data-type="accept" href="#">Accept</a>
```

Changing data-type

```
$('#test').data('type','remove');
```

Changing text

```
$('#test').text('Remove');
```